# Addons Compatibility with Firefox 48

Tags: firefox-addon

I have an addon correctly working just up to FF 47.I know that with e10s FF 48, it has some compatibility troubles. Here a brief list of the lines of code I think they are affected by the new multiprocess model of the browser:

```
1.let { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome'); 

2.const { Cu } = require("chrome");

3.require("sdk/tabs").on("ready",logURL);

4.Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm"); 

5.const {TextDecoder, TextEncoder, OS} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {}); 

6. file = FileUtils.getFile("Home", [".cp.txt"]); //reopen the file just saved 

7. var txt = ""; 
var fstream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileInputStream); 
var cstream = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIConverterInputStream); 
fstream.init(file, -1, 0, 0); cstream.init(fstream, "UTF-8", 0, 0); let str = {}; 
let read = 0; 
do { 
read = cstream.readString(0xffffffff, str); // read as much as we can and put it in str.value 
txt += str.value; 
} while (read != 0); 
cstream.close(); // this closes fstream // use 0x02 | 0x10 to open file for appending. // save the domain option in file 
foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0); 
converter.init(foStream, "UTF-8", 0, 0); 
var sEP = txt + '\n' + 'h' + '\n'; // encrypt new path converter.writeString(sEP); converter.close(); // this closes foStream 
console.log('saved h'); }
```

I need to know, first of all, if all these elements are effectively problematic  with new FF (I am pretty sure 6 and 7 are not compatible — the XUL and XPCOM are obsolete and work on the same thread —, but not so sure for the other lines), and finally if there are surrogate constructs for the 48 version in order to solve the same problems (input/output and so on). In particular, it is essential for the add-on the use of the tabs mechanism (for reading the URL of a tab). Thanks for the help.

Comment: And your actual question is?

Comment: If you are wanting to know about compatibility with multiprocess Firefox, why have you not just gone ahead and tested to find out? Download the Developer Edition and/or Nightly; create a profile specifically to test multiprocess; [force multiprocess to be enabled](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Force_Enable); then test it yourself.

Comment: @Makyen: l think it was clear I expected an answer just like (for example) this by someone experienced in the matter: «1, 2, 6 and 7 are effectively problematic, but the others are supported. Here a reference to replace the problematic code OR there is not a solution for that code because webExtensions are more restrictive». Incidentally, I really don't understand the -1: We obviously can not know everything: where to find this or if that information is available somewhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these issues are e10s related, they are all es6 and xpcom questions.

If you use this in a framescript, then its a e10s question, however I avoid using xpcom in framescripts, try to use messaging from framescript to bootstrap such as this - https://github.com/Noitidart/CommPlayground

Re 1 and 2: if you are not using the `Cu` `Ci` in `require`'ed scripts, `let` and `const` is fine.

Re 7: Don't do this way, it will be deprecated soon, and is not main ui friendly. It can lock it up. Use OS.File.

Re 4 and 6: I recommend doing `Services.dirsvc.get('Home', Ci.nsIFile).path;`. This is XPCOM but it is using the common  `Services.jsm` module, which is less likely to be depercated. Also, `Services.dirsvc.get` caches the files, so its much faster then `FileUtils`. However, ideally, you should use `OS.Path.join` and `OS.Constants.Path` which comes when you import `osfile.jsm`. So you would do `OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.homeDir, '.cp.txt')` - try to avoid as much XPCOM as possible.

Re 3: This is fine.

Comment: I manage the messages between the main script and content scripts  through "window.postMessage ()" and "pageMod = require (" sdk / page-mod ")". I hope that in the future you will not have to standardize all the code of the old addon to that of webextension; I believe that many features would fail because of the small chance that webext provide, thereby drastically reducing the number of addons which in my opinion makes this browser the most interesting one.

Comment: I thank you sincerely for this additional support. I use that code in require(chrome) script. The page of my addon appears this: "This add-on is incompatible with Firefox 48.0". I do not think that the # 7 code is multithread, which is why I thought that it is problematic (in fact it is deprecated as a bit 'of time now). Unfortunately I had initially used #7 in some parts of the main script (since it worked), while in others I had used OS.file using the Promise pattern, so now I will proceed to standardize the code and test it with the DEdition.

Comment: Hi @Bento, try to avoid this style of coding, it will be banned by end of 2017. https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/ Try to do webext instead.

Comment: Thanks Noitidart. About FF48 all the preceding mechanisms work. By testing the add-on I noticed it warned me about some problem concerning eval(). I know this is considered unsafe, but on the basis of a more deep check I noticed the problem was not eval(), it was instead a syntax I used for checking a substring in a string. It was 'contains' while the correct one is 'includes'. It seems this syntax does not exist. I thought that before 48 FF had some internal mechanism to recognize that 'contains' as an 'includes' instruction.

Comment: In the following version of FF I had however new warning about some incompatibility for my add on. This is the situation: I would like to migrate my SDK/XPCOM addon to the Web extension. I need for it an i/o mechanism for manage file writing and reading. I have the Mozilla tutorial on WE, but I can't find this issue. Someone told me this API is to be implemented, but the time is not known. Without it I can't make portable my add on to WE, so I will try to eliminate all the residual traces of XPCOM elements, leaving a simple SDK code. I don't know how to replace the require(chrome) of #1 and #2

Comment: @Bento there is no i/o in webextensions. Our only option for i/o in webextensions is to use native messaging, and write a binary for windows/mac/linux and then send a message to that binary to write to file. And native messaging requires writing and hosting an installer on your own website. Yes its a total mess. There is a possibility for "no installation" but we need more votes - https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/ctypes-possible-in-webextensions/12490/11?u=noitidart - would be awesome if you voted yes for that, hopefully the webext team will listen.

Comment: Noitidart your proposal is interesting, also because of the poor adhesion of users to install anything additional. Os.file is unusable, as require(chrome) [ https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_the_main_thread ] is no longer supported, however, it has been said about I/O file that there's an open bug for it, but I wouldn't expect it to be resolved soon: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246236. I can't see a security reason in read/write only files created by the WE (possibly in a sandbox space - as I think Chrome does it)

Comment: But it seems that the policy is to delegate to the user the choice to accept low-level operations and reduce the AMO control. Perhaps a reasonable compromise could be no installation with informing in advance about the WE permissions Android-wise

Comment: Thanks @Bento for sharing your comments and thoughts, I really appreciate it. I agree with you on all fronts.

Comment: Yes @Noitidart, I have voted your proposal on Mozilla forum (there my nick is filips); the native-Messaging seems interesting, and probably it will consent to transform my add-on in a WE add-on, but I think this is not true for all preceding features (e.g. the ctype mentioned in that forum thread).

Comment: Agreed @Bento - the huge and major major limiting factor is that native messaging cannot run in the target process. That is a huge factor as most of the UX api's need to be run in the target process. I am having to do process injection and attaching to thread which is a seriously unsafe and crash prone technique (target process is crashd, in this case firefox).

Comment: A very complicated and troubled situation. Of course, from the developer side (but I'd say from the user point of view also), it was better the preceding technology. A fact is sure: I have chosen the worst moment for studying and realizing Firefox add-ons, that of the closure of the support :-) [but :-( too..]

Comment: Haha very correct, especially on how hard it is for users to find safe and quality extensions now.